# Need help in list view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new bea to android and want to open a list view/menu (see image:2) after click on image/button (see image:1). I am not sure whether it is list or dialog or some other component. Please help me out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: its spinner i think in action bar

Comment: This is the Spinner representation in Holo light theme

Answer (score 1):

That is **Drop-Down navigation for the ActionBar**, you can check official documentation for the same: [Adding Drop-down Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown).

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mNavigationCallback);
// It takes your SpinnerAdapter and ActionBar.OnNavigationListener.
```

Check Examples:

1. [Adding Drop down navigation to action bar in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-drop-down-navigation-to-action-bar-in-android/)
2. [Adapter part 1 on Styling Android](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1679)

### Update:

To provide app compatibility for the lower Android version, I would suggest you to include [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library, once you will download it, you will be able to access many samples too.

Answer (score 1):

its `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`

check this [link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) **Because it Working for All Android OS Version**

in that many sample available for more details check this [artical](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

[image]

Comment: Its spinner in ActionBar known as Drop-down navigation, check my answer.

Comment: @PareshMayani: have you any issue with me. why adding not required comment below my answer. i have saggest him actionbarsherlock which is same as you saggest and its work for all ANDROID OS i think it is very good for every Android Developer. so dont worry.

Comment: Simple Spinner and Spinner in ActionBar both are different things my dear.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Spinner in Android. Please check below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

If you want to implement behavior like GMail, then you need to override getView method of your Spinner Adapter

Comment: Yes It's spinner but inside ActionBar.